# Connect to OpenVPN server with different client

Tags: vpn, openvpn, connect

If I create OpenVPN server on my Linux machine, can I connect to that server (from Windows) using different client for example SoftEther VPN or built-in VPN client in Windows?

Or I have to use OpenVPN client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use the OpenVPN client since they all use different protocols. The SoftEther server however creates a server with different protocols.

[image: SoftEther VPN protocols]

Comment: So if I create SoftEther VPN server then I can use all other protocols as well?

Comment: @tomsk Yes, as per the diagram.